# Weird str_replace behaviour

Tags: php

It's more of a clarification than a question, I have this code here:

```
$itemSizeArray = array('S' => 'Small', 'M' => 'Medium', 'L' => 'Large', 'X' => 'XLarge');
$modifierSize = 'X';
$submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION'] = "Small Toppings";
echo str_replace($itemSizeArray, $itemSizeArray[$modifierSize], $submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION']);
```

It works fine in all cases **except** when `$modifierSize = 'X';`, 
It outputs `"XXLarge Toppings"` (double X). -- problem

In other cases i.e. when `$modifierSize = 'L';` it outputs `Large Toppings`. -- no problem

After I read the documentation a bit more I fixed the code with this line

```
echo str_replace($itemSizeArray['S'], $itemSizeArray[$modifierSize], $submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION']);
```

and it works fine, but I did not understand why.

[this] **What was the procedure of the first bit of code that caused this behavior?** [/this]

**Edit:** I had [this] in bold and the forced edit from another user removed the bold. I marked Stanislav's answer as the correct one because he is answering the *actual* question, rather than what *he thought I asked* based on the question's info. Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](http://php.net/str_replace) says:

> If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement
>   string is used for every value of search.

So "Small Toppings" becomes "XLarge Toppings" and then, in string "XLarge Toppings" Large becomes XLarge and result is "XXLarge Toppings".

Here is smaller example to understand what is happening:

```
$itemSizeArray = array('Small', 'Large');
var_dump(str_replace($itemSizeArray, 'XLarge', "Small Toppings"));exit;
```

Comment: Thanks :D, Now that you mentioned it its kinda obvious!

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to replace and with what in your target string? A reason why it's showing weird  behavior might be because str_replace can expect an array of values for both the first (search for) and second (replace with) argument. In your original code sample you were supplying key-value pairs as the needle (first argument).

For example, if you want to search for S, M, L etc. and replace them with Small, Medium, Large etc., you can try the following:

```
str_replace(array_keys($itemSizeArray), array_values($itemSizeArray), $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to achieve this is

```
  $itemSizeArray = array('S' => 'Small', 'M' => 'Medium', 'L' => 'Large', 'X' => 'XLarge');
  $modifierSize = 'X';
  $submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION'] = "Small Toppings";

  echo str_replace($submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION'], $itemSizeArray[$modifierSize], $submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION']);
```

But still why  complicate things . You can just change every time you need it the value of the menu variable

```
 $submenuModifierDescription['SUME_DESCRIPTION'] = $itemSizeArray[$modifierSize];
```

Your code returns the weird result in X case because str_replace function first parameter is an array.

Answer (score 0):

itemSizeArray is an array, while str_replace is replacing STRING.
If you want to replace all of the values in the array, you should do a foreach loop:

foreach ($itemSizeArray as $key=>$var) and replace what you want

But as i see, you're trying to get "XLarge toppings" if you enter "X", "Large toppings" if you have "L", etc.etc.

in this case, this could be the code:

```
$itemSizeArray = array('S' => 'Small', 'M' => 'Medium', 'L' => 'Large', 'X' => 'XLarge');
$modifierSize = 'X';
echo ($itemSizeArray[$modifierSize].' Toppings');
```

This is, because the itemsizearray is already an associative array, so you can address the elements by key.